# How to change the transparency of a continuous scale legend when calling the alpha argument in a geom in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need the alpha for the legend of the continuous scale colourbar to match that of the call in the geom.

```
mpg %>% ggplot(aes(x = displ, y = cty)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = hwy), alpha = 0.33)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a color-gradient scale with a built-in `alpha`. For example, in the code below, the `85` tacked onto the end of the color values sets the alpha for each color (85 is 1/3 of 256 on the hexadecimal scale of the color and alpha values):

```
mpg %>% ggplot(aes(x = displ, y = cty)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = hwy), alpha = 0.33) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "#132B4385", high = "#56B1F785")
```

Compare:

```
theme_set(theme_classic())

gridExtra::grid.arrange(
  mpg %>% ggplot(aes(x = displ, y = cty)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = hwy), alpha = 0.33),
  mpg %>% ggplot(aes(x = displ, y = cty)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = hwy), alpha = 0.33) +
    scale_colour_gradient(low = "#132B4385", high = "#56B1F785"),
  ncol=2
)
```

[image]

Comment: The first example discretises my legend, I don't see any alpha difference in the second one.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the discretizing of the legend. Sorry about that. I've deleted that approach. For the `scale_colour_gradient` approach, I've post examples showing what I'm getting when I add the alpha.

Comment: The solution works on my laptop. Must be something up with my R environment on my desktop.